Prove that $\log_2(n) \le \sqrt{2n}$ for all $n\ge1$
I have proven by induction that for every $k\ge4$, $\log_2(2^k)\le 2^{k/2}$. I need to prove that $\log_2(n)\le \sqrt{2n}$ for all $n\ge1$ by using the fact that $\log_2(2^k)$ for the smallest integer $k$ such that $n\le 2^k$.
My thinking is that if there exists a smallest integer $k$ such that $n\le 2^k$, $\log_2(n)\le \log_2(2^k) = k \le 2^{k/2}$ using what's been proven. Since $n \le 2^k$, take square roots of both sides I get $\sqrt{n} \le 2^{k/2}$. However, my confusion is in the comparison between $k$ and $\sqrt{n}$. If $k\le \sqrt{n}$, then I can easily conclude that $k \le \sqrt{2n}$ hence $\log_2{n}\le \sqrt{2n}$. If $k \ge \sqrt{n}$, I don't know how to proceed. Am I overthinking this question? Please give some guidance.

Can you use the fact that both are strictly increasing functions and look for a common tangent? It might be easier than an induction proof.

For $n\geq 1$ you can pick $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k\leq n<2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^k$.

$k$ is the smallest integer such that $n\le 2^k$, so both $2^{k-1}<n$ and $2^k < 2n$.

For the interested, the proof of the first part: Induction to prove that $\log_2 2^k \leq 2^{k/2}$

The question chose $k$ to be the smallest integer such that $n\le 2^k$, so $n \not \le 2^{k-1}$ but $2^{k-1} < n$. Multiply this by $2$ to get $2^k < 2n$:
$$2^{k-1} < n \le 2^k < 2n$$
For $k \ge 4$, i.e. $n > 2^{4-1} = 8$, continue with your attempt to apply $\log_2\left(2^k\right) \le 2^{k/2}$:
$$\log_2(n) \le \log_2\left(2^k\right) \le 2^{k/2} < (2n)^{1/2} = \sqrt{2n}$$

For $n$ where $5\le n \le 8$,
$$\log_2(n) \le \log_2(8) = 3 < \sqrt{10} \le \sqrt{2n}$$
For $n$ where $ 4< n < 5 < \sqrt{32}$,
$$\log_2(n) < \log_2 \left(\sqrt{32}\right) = \frac52 < \sqrt{8} < \sqrt{2n}$$
For $n$ where $2 < n \le 4$,
$$\log_2(n) \le \log_2(4) = 2 = \sqrt 4 < \sqrt{2n}$$
For $n$ where $1\le n \le 2$,
$$\log_2(n) \le \log_2(2) = 1 < \sqrt 2 \le \sqrt{2n}$$
And outside the question's requirement, for $n$ where $0 < n < 1$,
$$\log_2(n) < \log_2(1) = 0 < \sqrt{2n}$$

Using algebra.
Consider the function
$$f(x)= \sqrt{2x}-\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2x}}-\frac{1}{x \log (2)}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{1}{x^2 \log (2)}-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} x^{3/2}}$$
The first derivative cancels at $$x_*=\frac{2}{\log ^2(2)}\quad \implies f(x_*)=\frac{2+\log \left(\frac{\log
   ^2(2)}{2}\right)}{\log (2)}=0.827857$$
The second derivative confirms that $x_*$ corresponds to the minimum.
So, the claim is true $\forall n >0$.
